# Can't get a content in PHP

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
function get_vk($url) {
    $str = file_get_contents("http://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url=" . $url);
    if (!$str) return 0;
    return preg_match('/^VK.Share.count\((\d+),\s+(\d+)\);$/i', $rq, $i) ? (int) $i[2] : 0;
}
```

But this function always return 0, because `$str` is NULL. But if we just put this link

```
https://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url=http://stackoverflow.com
```

into the browser it will return `VK.Share.count(1, 43);` Where is the problem ?

Comment: so your browser can fetch it, but not your serveR? start looking into **WHY** the server can't. did you get it blacklisted for abusing the service? firewall preventing outgoing port 80 connections? Your question is unanswerable right now.

Comment: Check out if you could be blacklisted from the vk.com service.

Comment: In internet all use this function. Maybe it will work with curl?

Comment: I don't think `$str` will be `null`; perhaps it's `false` or an empty string?

Comment: Paul, no it can't be so.

Comment: With `https` the same result

Comment: Some hosts (like Dreamhost) don't allow file_get_contents.

Comment: I don't use hosting. And `file_get_contents` works

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the input string to preg_match.

The code should be written like this:

```
function get_vk($url) {
    $str = file_get_contents("http://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url=" . $url);
    if (!$str) return 0;
    preg_match('/^VK.Share.count\((\d+),\s+(\d+)\);$/i', $str, $matches);
    $rq = $matches[1];

    return $rq;
}

echo get_vk('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

You can read up on the syntax for preg_match at http://php.net/preg_match.

Comment: If my solution was helpful to you, would you mind clicking the check mark to accept the answer? Thank you!